# dynamically creating php files and tables

Tags: php, content-management-system, createprocess, multi-user

I'm new to PHP and after writing a couple CMS' I'd like to try something more complex.

What I want to do is create a script whereby I can create a whole user area with functions, classes and forms etc. Something like a personal admin panel for the user but within their own directory. The aim would be to then create their own webpage within the webpage. I assume this is a common task as I guess it is what all blogs, portfolio sites, facebook, youtube do.

I have been experimenting with `mkdir` `fopen` `fwrite` and similar commands but I don't know how I could use these - without LOTS of code - to create fully functioning user areas like an admin panel.

After writing this I'm seeing problems in scaling this. If users are always creating files then this will eventually take up a lot of server space. Would a better way to do this be via  MVC in a framework like Codeigniter?

Or would the best way to do this be by using `php copy()`?

Comment: would wordpress be a better option for you ??

Comment: @Subash Yes perhaps, but I want to create it myself in order to learn more PHP

Comment: you should play with `HMVC` Bonfire http://cibonfire.com/
also see the functionality of CI Bonfire module Builder

Comment: see my comment again Module builder of Bonfire should teach u the technique

Comment: you could try Codeigniter frame work then, its lightweight but very powerfull http://codeigniter.com/

Comment: @Subash yes I was thinking about using codeignter. This seems like the most efficient way, and for scaling. Its a bit of learning curve though but time spent there will pay off later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to make facebook without lots of code. Good luck :)

But to create a seperate userarea you dont physically create files for those users. You have a database that stores the data per user and you have a php file that selects the right data for the right user.

The example below is a very simplistic proof of concept, and should not be used directly.

you have a table users

```
id | Name
1  | Elisa
2  | Hugo
```

And a table content

```
id | UserId | MyBlogEntry
1  | 1      | Hello, this is my blog
2  | 1      | Hello, this is my 2nd blog
3  | 2      | I dont like blogging
```

Now you have a page called usercontent.php which accepts a username as variable. You call it like `usercontent.php?user=Elise` or `usercontent.php?user=Hugo`

The content:
Keep in mind I left out all validation checks for simplicity. You need to make sure there are valid users and no SQL Injection

```
<?
$user = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : ''

if (empty($user)) {
  echo 'I dont know this user';
  exit;
}

echo $user.'\'s Blog<hr>';

$query = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE UserId=(SELECT Id FROM users WHERE name='".$user."')";

//execute mysqli query

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo '<p>' . $row['MyBlogEntry'] . '<p>';
}
?>
```

The ouput would be be something like this for Elisa

```
Elisa's blog
---------------------
Hello, this is my blog

Hello, this is my 2nd blog
```

And for Hugo

```
Hugo's blog
---------------------
I dont like blogging
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense and I'm already using a method like this to show users only their own records. But you wouldn't create a table for the content of each user? All content in one table?

Comment: You would have one database and multiple tables. You could have a table for users, one for blogs, one for settings, one for portfolio, one for comments, one for ... etc